# Use of HTML5 download option in button using javascript

Tags: javascript, extjs, hyperlink

I want to write a Javascript function which downloads json file by adding variables into it. Something like this https://jsfiddle.net/cowboy/hHZa9/

```
var obj = {a: 123, b: "4 5 6"};
var data = "text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj));

$('<a href="data:' + data + '" download="data.json">download JSON</a>').appendTo('#container');
```

But now I want replace anchor tag with button.
I am using ExtJS 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Extjs button like this:

```
var obj = {
        a: 123,
        b: "4 5 6"
    },
    data = "text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj));

Ext.widget('button', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

    text: 'Download',

    href: 'data:' + data,

    autoEl: {
        tag: 'a',
        download: 'data.json'
    }
});
```

Working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1chg

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things..

1. Style your `a` tag so that it looks like a `button`.
2. Put a `button` inside the `a` tag

   ```
   $('<a href="data:' + data + '" download="data.json"><button>download JSON</button></a>').appendTo('#container');
   ```

as `button` does not have a `download` attribute so you need to use the `a` tag.

Comment: I am using ExtJS and don't have option to add anchor tag at my desired location.